# Detail Page Button with JavaScript on Opportunity Record

Tags: apex, javascript

I have a requirement where in I need to read all the Names of OpportunityLineItems and then proceed with the logic.

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/18.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/18.0/apex.js")} 

var value1 ={!Opportunity.Probability}; 
alert(value1);
/* Alerts opportunity probability **/
```

**Now what does this return ?**

```
{!OpportunityLineItem.ProductName__c}
```

Is it an array of OLI names?

Should i  read the result as like shown below?

```
var myArray = new Array();
myArray = {!OpportunityLineItem.ProductName__c} ;
```

**ProductName__c is a formula field populated with Product name**.

Am confused and i get error as undefined;
Please suggest a better way to read oli names !! 
Thank you .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can read your Opp Line Items depending on the current Opp ID:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/18.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/18.0/apex.js")} 

// Quering the database
var result = sforce.connection.query("Select ProductName__c From OpportunityLineItem Where OpportunityId = '{!Opportunity.Id}'");

// Getting all records from the query to the array
var records = result.getArray("records");

// Getting the product name of the first array entry
var prodName = records[0].ProductName__c;

alert(prodName);
```